# Checking if element is in tuple using if condition

Tags: python, tuples

I am trying to check if there is a certain digit inside my tuple using an if statement, but finding it hard. Whats wrong here?

```
def racaman(x):
    y = x
    w = (0,)
    for i in range(y):
        k = w[i]-x[i]
        if k == i in w:
            w = w + ((w[i]+x[i]),)
        else:
            w = w + ((w[i]-x[i]),)
```

Comment: please indent your code... this is not readable

Comment: It's just `element in tuple`. I'm not sure why you have an   equals statement there

Comment: And please ask a more specific question, and explain what you've tried, and what problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace 3 in the if condition to find a specific digit

```
def raceman(x):
    #assuming x is tuple
    if 3 in x:
        print("found")
    else:
        print("not found")
raceman((1,2,3,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your question, paste code properly.
I am not sure what you are asking for but, I guess:

```
tupl = (1,2,3,4,5)
   if 1 in tupl:
       print('y')
   else:
       print('n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a list instead

```
def racaman(x):
    w = [0]
    for i in range(x):
        k = w[i]-x[i]
        if k in w:  # fix this 
            w.append(w[i]+x[i])
        else:
            w.append(k)  # already calculated 
    return w # did you want to return that?
```

Answer (score 0):

This could simply be a matter of checking like so:

```
>>>n in t
```

Where n is the *digit* and t is the *tuple*, for example:

```
>>>2 in (1,2,3)
True
```

However it is not enough if you are looking for a digit and the elements are strings:

```
>>>2 in ('a1','a2','a3') #won't return desired output since digit '2' is part of a string
False
```

**If** so, you would need to resort to a more adaptive method, iterating over the elements of the tuple and testing each one with an appropriate *regular expression* (`import re`).